# How to get max(colName) value where colName is of Type TimeStamp in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having following table structure
[image]
and having the following Data in this table
[image]
Now I want to query in such a way so that I can have values of all the columns + the value of max(currenttime) for a particular game_id.

i am running the following query
SELECT _id, game_id, inning_id, scoretype, oponentonescore, oponenttwoscore, currenttime, MAX( currenttime ) AS latest FROM  `game_scores` WHERE game_id =  '2268'

and as a result i am getting only one row as in the following result
[image]
But i want want all rows matching the criteria(i.e. game id 2268)

How to compose Query to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm sorry, i haven't actually tested this, but maybe something like this would do the trick:

```
SELECT
    _id,
    game_id,
    inning_id,
    scoretype,
    oponentonescore,
    oponenttwoscore,
    currenttime,
    latest
FROM
    game_scores
JOIN (
    SELECT
        MAX(currenttime) AS latest
    FROM
        game_scores
    WHERE
        game_id = '2268'
) AS latest_calculation
WHERE game_id = '2268';
```

although this solution is heavier on the database than it is heavy on the application to figure it out after the query is back from the database (like alex suggested).

Comment: Superb U make my day. Although this can be done by another inefficient ways but this way is the best one. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

Your `MAX()` is an aggregate type function and gets one value for multiple rows.

So remove it and use something like this with PHP...

```
$maxTime = 0;

foreach($rows as $row) {
   $maxTime = max($maxTime, strtotime($row['currenttime']));
}
```

...or run another query, though the above should be sufficient...

```
SELECT MAX(`currenttime`) AS `latest`
  FROM `game_scores`
 WHERE `game_id` = '2268'
```

Formatted in your convenience [*OMG Ponies*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies) style.

Comment: ya i know this so how to make a query to achieve deesired result

Comment: @Abhishek Gupta Remove `MAX()` and you can calculate it with PHP's `max()`, or, you could run another query.

Comment: I dont want to run another query because current time stamp value may change when i run another . I was thinking to achieve this using SQL itself using some nested query concept. is it possible?  :)

Comment: @Abhishek Gupta Can you use a variation of the PHP code in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Something on the lines of this query would do the required. NOT TESTED.

```
 SELECT _id, game_id, inning_id, scoretype, oponentonescore, oponenttwoscore,
    currenttime,maxtime from game_scores OUTER join (SELECT _id,MAX(currenttime)
    as maxtime from game_scores) as t on t._id = game_scores._id  where game_id = '2268';
```

Comment: this result in one row only :(

Comment: sorry I had used inner join. Try an outer join.